# Two columns of dates and aggregates

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    Identified_Date, 
    Referred_Date, 
    count(IdentifiedmemberID) as id_volume, 
    count(ReferredMemberID) as refer_volume
FROM MyTable
```

It returns a list like this:

```
Identified_Date  Referred_Date  id_volume  refer_volume

2/7/18           2/7/18         2          10

2/14/18          2/21/18        8          4
```

How can I get the dates to line up so that IF there's a matching date, it's next to the one that matches.  OR (ideally) combines both the date columns so it looks like this:

```
Date  id_volume  refer_volume

2/7/18     2          10

2/14/18    8          0

2/21/18    0          4
```

Comment: So you're needing to partially pivot the `Date` column when the `Identified_Date` and `Referred_Date` don't match? Why would you need to do this?

Comment: So I can have a report of the number of ID_volume and refer_volume by date.

Comment: No, your query does not return the list shown. It returns one row, because you aggregate without any `GROUP BY` clause. Please show the real query. What is unique in your table? Can there be multiple records per `Identified_Date`? Multiple records per `Referred_Date`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL Statement which complete your requirements.

```
Select Temp.Common_Date, Max(Temp.id_volume) As id_volume, Max(Temp.refer_volume) As refer_volume
From
(       
    Select MT.Identified_Date As Common_Date, count(IdentifiedmemberID) as id_volume, 0 As refer_volume
    From MyTable MT

    UNION

    Select MT.Referred_Date As Common_Date, 0 As id_volume, count(ReferredMemberID) as refer_volume
    From MyTable MT
)Temp
group by Common_Date
```

Let me know if any question!

Comment: Right idea but you are missing some `group by`s.

Comment: Can you comment your output?

Comment: You're a saint! Thank you!